# Properly scaling BigDecimal

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I have a situation where I want to scale values but in certain situations I'm getting an exception that indicates that rounding is required.

Lets say I have the numbers `-9.999999` and `9.999999`

Lets also say that I only care about precision up to 4 points after the decimal place.  How can I scale both of these numbers properly without checking if the value is positive or negative?

If for example, I use `RoundingMode.FLOOR`, I get:

```
9.999999 scales to 99999
-9.999999 scales to -100000
```

What I would like is `9.9999` and `-9.9999`, respectively.

Do I really need to check for the sign here?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: I just updated, sorry I forgot to do that.

Comment: HALF_UP results in 100000 and 100000

Comment: [RoundingMode.DOWN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN)

Comment: Make it an answer @GriffeyDog, perhaps with an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RoundingMode.DOWN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN) always rounds toward zero, so that should be what you're looking for. That is, it will never increment your final digit when it rounds. It's equivalent to truncating your value at the specified scale.

Comment: Thanks. I was a little confused by that but it makes sense now.

Comment: `FLOOR` rounds towards negative infinity, which is what was leading to the behavior you were seeing.  Read the docs!

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal bg1, bg2;

bg1 = new BigDecimal("123.12678");

// set scale of bg1 to 2 in bg2 using floor as rounding mode
    bg2 = bg1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);

String str = bg1 + " after changing the scale to 2 and rounding is
                 " +bg2;

// print bg2 value
    System.out.println( str );
```

Gives you output: `123.12678 after changing the scale to 2 and rounding is 123.12`

Using RoundingMode.FLOOR
RoundingMode.Floor acts as RoundingMode.DOWN for possitive numbers and as RoundingMode.UP for negative numbers

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00");
        decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        System.out.println("FORMAT:" + decimalFormat.format(-94.5));<br>The result will be: FORMAT: - 95
```

RoundingMode.CEILING acts as RoundingMode.UP for possitive numbers and as RoundingMode.DOWN for negative

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00");
        decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        System.out.println("FORMAT:" + decimalFormat.format(-94.5));<br>The result will be:FORMAT: -94
```